# python - Manually execute typing constraints using typing classes

Tags: python-3.x, typing

I want to verify the type of some parameter, preferably using the `typing` definitions

e.g:

```
from typing import List, Dict

def func(param1, param2):
     assert param1 is of type Dict[str, int] # How can this be done?
     assert param2 is of type List[Any] # How can this be done?
```

It is easy for non complex types. `assert isinstance(param1, str)`

The question is obviously simplified to make it clear

Comment: The `typing` module seems only used for type hints - no enforcement actually.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I'm wondering if still there is some way to use it

Comment: Since python lists and dictionaries arent limited to single types, you'd have to enumerate the collections and check each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use libraries like [enforce](https://github.com/RussBaz/enforce) or [typeguard](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard) to enforce the type annotations at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

According to [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), it's only meant to make type hints more readable, and no type checking is actually enforced by Python.

Since lists and dictionaries may contain arbitrary types (for dicts, they must be hashable - but still "almost arbitrary"), the only way to do this is to iterate over the collection and check every single item.

```
assert isinstance(param1, dict)
for k, v in param1.items():
    assert isinstance(k, str)
    assert isinstance(v, int)
```